# JQuery show/hide field not working properly the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

I am having some trouble with this snippet of code. It works, but only after I click on the radio button it is being affected by twice. When I click the button the first time, it does not work, but if I give it a second click, it will. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
function hide(){
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[id$='yes']").click(function(){
         $("div#hidden").fadeOut(2000);
      });
   });
};
```

This is what I have in my header. I have another just like only it's called show() which is affected by another radio button. When you click on one it hides a div, when you click on the other it shows it.

Here is the radio button which affects the script to whether the div is hidden or shown.

```
<input type="radio" name="field1" id="yes" value="Y" onClick="hide();" />Yes
```

Again, there is another just like it only it is no. Now, the div being hidden is:

```
<div id="hidden"><input type="text" name="extrafield1" id="no_box" size="20" maxlength="20" /></div>
```

Again, when the No radio button is clicked it should appear, when the Yes radio button is clicked it should hide. It works, but you must click on the radio button twice.

This snippet hides the div when the page loads:

```
function loadHidden(){
    $("div#hidden").hide();
}

<body onLoad="loadHidden()">
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you're using jQuery and obtrusive JavaScript and `$(document).ready(function(){..})` inside an event handler function. What's the reason for that?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not very skilled in jQuery, and I'm still getting used to it. This is the way I have seen the script being run, and so applied it to my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your document.ready event defined within the hide function, so the event for the click function isn't registered when the document first loads.  Try a structure like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[id$='yes']").click(function(){
        $("div#hidden").fadeOut(2000);
    });

    $("input[id$='no']").click(function(){
        $("div#hidden").fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

This way, the click event is all set up when the document is ready, and you won't need the onClick attributes on your radio buttons.

Comment: Chuck Spohr: Thanks for your answer. This worked perfectly. The fact the $(document).ready was within the function never occurred to me. Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Comment: You bet.  I've been there too.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `hide()` was causing a problem. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNy95/).

Answer (score 0):

Just write your logic in document.ready in element click events it should work.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':radio[name=field1]').change(function () {
     if($(this).val()=='Y'){
       $("div#hidden").fadeOut(2000);
     }
     else{
       $("div#hidden").fadeIn(2000);
     }
  });
});
```